# SwiftUI NavigationView remove white space

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a `HomeView`

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
             NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView()) {
                 if session.userInSession?.activated != 1 {
                     completionText(message: "Complete Your Profile")
                 } else {
                     completionText(message: "Edit Your Profile")
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ProfileView` is not wrapped in a navigation view nor has a bar title:

```
VStack {
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But my `ProfileView` is also accessible from my `SettingView`

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView()) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I access my `ProfileView` from the setting screen, it displays fine. But when I access it from my `HomeView` it creates white space at the top:

[image]

When I go through Settings its fine:

[image]

How can I remove this white space above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like your `HomeView`/s `NavigationView` has `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)` or automatic, which is by default `.large`, but your `SettingView` has `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` (taking into account divider below `< Setting`), so you see different height of title bars.

Of course it is assumption due not absent of detailed code, but possible solution to make it same would be add explicit mode for `ProfileView`, eg:

```
VStack {
   ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
   }
}.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)     // << here !!
```

Comment: but how to handle for below iOS 14 ?

Comment: @DanielWijono `.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)`

Answer (score 0):

This *space* is probably an empty title of your NavigationView.

You can try hiding your navigation bar title:

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        ...
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

As a test try setting `.navigationBarTitle("Some title")` and see if you still see this empty space or if it's replaced by *Some title* text.